# How to check if the entry in a table exists in another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

```
Output
ID Name 
1   A
2   B
3   C
4   D

TEST
ID Name
2   B
3   C
```

I would like to create a new table which would look like this:

```
Output
ID Name TEST
1   A    no
2   B    Yes
3   C    Yes
4   D    no
```

Currently, I have created a new column on table Output:

```
   ID Name TEST
    1   A    NULL
    2   B    NULL
    3   C    NULL
    4   D    NULL
```

and used this query

```
SELECT * FROM OUTPUT,
CASE WHEN OUTPUT.ID = TEST.ID
THEN 'Yes'
ELSE 'No'
END;
```

But I get an error, saying "Incorrect synthax near the keyword 'case'". What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a join and then use `CASE` to check if exists or not

```
SELECT o.*,
CASE WHEN t.ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END Test
FROM OUTPUT o
LEFT JOIN test t ON o.ID = t.ID
ORDER BY o.ID
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d95fb/4)